# Parsing full json in Xaml

Tags: c#, json, windows-store-apps

I have json code:

```
{
responses:
[{
photo:[{url:"YYYY"},{url:"YYYY"}]
},
{
photo:[{url:"XXXX"},{url:"XXXX"}]
}]
}
```

In my app i'm trying to parse response and photos in each of this response. I've tried to use gridview inside main gridview but it doesn't work. Is there any method to implement that?
Thanks for the help!

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("ЧЧЧЧЧ");

string Text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

List<RootObject> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(Text);
lvMain3.ItemsSource = values;
cvsMain.Source = values[0].trends;
```

---

```
public class Trend
{
    public string Query { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private UIElement _control = new MyUserControl1();
    public UIElement Control { get { return _control; } }
}

public class Location
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Woeid { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string As_of { get; set; }
    public List<Trend> trends { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

And my xaml code where i put gridview inside main gridview:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="cvsMain" ItemsPath="Persons"/>
</Page.Resources>
.... 
<GridView x:Name="lvMain3">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="410" Width="410" Background="Gray">
                <GridView x:Name="lvMain4">
                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Height="410" Width="410" Background="Gray">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                </GridView>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

actual JSON:

```
 [
   {
      "as_of":"2012-08-31T15:31:55Z",
      "trends":[
         {
            "query":"%23GDTHATXX",
            "name":"#GDTHATXX",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=%23GDTHATXX",
            "events":null
         },
         {
            "query":"%23UnMundoEnElQue",
            "name":"#UnMundoEnElQue",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=%23UnMundoEnElQue",
            "events":null
         }
      ]
   },
 {
      "as_of":"2012-08-31T15:31:55Z",
      "trends":[
         {
            "query":"%23GDTHATXX",
            "name":"#GDTHATXX",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=%23GDTHATXX",
            "events":null
         },
         {
            "query":"%23UnMundoEnElQue",
            "name":"#UnMundoEnElQue",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=%23UnMundoEnElQue",
            "events":null
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Is this WPF? Silverlight? Also, define what doesn't work exactly.

Comment: Store app. Gridview inside main gridview doesn't work

Comment: Why are you using `GridView` within `GridView`? What's your expected output? Can you show actual JSON?